# How do I make a JLabel's text wrap based on available space?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, word-wrap

There are already several questions on this site asking how to make a `JLabel` wrap text. I have read them, and am not asking the (totally) same question. So slow down your "flag as duplicate" hammers.

Other questions have solved the JLabel-wrap-text problem by either

1. Using HTML tags to make the text wrap to a specified length, or
2. Using a `JTextArea` instead of a `JLabel`, which has a wrapping property.

My problem with both of these methods is that they have a fixed width. In the first, you have to specify a width within the html or set a maximum size on the `JLabel`. In the second, you have to set a preferred size on the `JTextArea`, and if you don't, it comes with a default size.

**Is there a method to making `JLabel` text wrap only when restricted by its containers' sizes?** Basically, the goal of this is to have the Layout Manager handling the width that restricts and forces wrapping. This means that a resized window might change the text within the label - as more space becomes available fewer lines are made as a result of wrapping, and as less space becomes available more lines are wrapped.

I'd prefer a solution that word wraps at minimum. If your solution can also just wrap by characters, brownie points for you.

Comment: In the future, using better tag keywords will generally get you an answer faster. I only happened on this question by chance. I added "java, swing".

Answer (score 4):

> . In the second, you have to set a preferred size on the JTextArea, and if you don't, it comes with a default size.

You typically specify the row/columns of the text area so the text area can determine a preferred size to be used when the frame is packed.

However, if you use a layout manager that is able to resize the width of the text area, then the width will be calculated on the space available.

For example `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` will always fill the width. `GridBagLayout` also supports filling the width of the component in the cell.

So a text area with the appropriate layout manager should solve your problem.

> If your solution can also just wrap by characters, brownie points for you.

A JTextArea also support character wrapping.